# Is $f(z) = |g(z)| e ^{ i \text{Arg}(g(z))}$ Continious, Differentiable, Analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Given an analytical function $g(z)$ on $\mathbb C$, we want to look at the function and tell if it's continious, diffentiable or analytic.

$$f(z) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
|g(z)| e ^{ i \text{Arg}(g(z))},\ g(z)\notin \mathbb{R}^- \cup \left \{ 0 \right \}\\ 
0,\  g(z)\in \mathbb{R}^- \cup \left \{ 0 \right \}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I know that at points of the first kind, $f$ can be localy expressed as $g$ and hence is analytic aswell. However, the points of the 2nd kind seem very problematic.

If it matters, in the original context we were given $g(z) = z^4-1$.

Comment: The points of the second kind are those where $z^4$ is real and $\le 1$, so either of the form $\pm t, \pm it$ with $0\le t\le 1$ or of the form $(1\pm i)t$ with $t\in\Bbb R$. At these points, $f$ will not be continuous (except that it *is* continuous at the endpoints $\pm1,\pm i$).

Answer (score 0):

$|f(\frac  1 n)|=|n^{-4}-1| \to 1$ and $\frac  1 n \to 0$. But $f(0)=0$ so $f$ is not even continuous.

Comment: At $0$, what about any other point for which $z^4-1 \in \mathbb{R}^-$?

Comment: @Theorem Same thing happens at all those points. $f$ is holomorphic  in $\{z: g(z) \notin \mathbb R^{-1} \cup \{0\}\}$ but the moment you add any point where $g(z) \in \mathbb R^{-1} \cup \{0\}$ you lose continuity.

Comment: Okay... but how does one show that?

Comment: @Theorem Suppose $g(z_0)=-t$ where $t>0$. Then $f(z_0)=0$ by definition. But $|f(z)|=|g(z)| \to |g(z_0)|=t>0$ as $z \to z_0$..